How to pass the react native component embed with WindowManager in android?
I am facing problem to integrate the react native component
public class OverlayViewService extends Service {
 
  private ImageButton closeDialog;
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    startMyOwnForeground(); 
    else
    startForeground(1, new Notification());
    Toast.makeText(this, "service started onCreate in ON CREATE RULE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    initOverlayView();
  }
  private void initOverlayView() {
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    // windowManager.addView(overlayView, params);
    windowManager.addView(overlayView, params);
  
}
 
}

I am trying to load a react native component in WindowManager but { overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);}  is not able to load react native component. App getting crashed after calling this service.
I want to load
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null);

`the react native component here.` ` Help me to fix this issue.`
